# Google Compute Engine - Upgrading from GCP Free Tier

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I know that on GCP, after your free trial period ends any CE resources will be terminated and other services will enter a 30-day grace period, as described here:

https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end

However, that document somewhat vaguely describes what happens to my CE resources when, for example, I go ahead and perform an [account upgrade](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#how-to-upgrade) *before* my trial period and/or trial credit expires.

Will an account upgrade still end the trial as if the trial resources depleted, or will it let you keep everything and start paying for it normally?

Comment: Um, nothing? What were you thinking might happen?

Comment: Well, it does say that you still have 30 days to "recover" something after you've upgraded. Whether that includes CE as an option or not is not explained. This suggests that "upgrading" might still end the trial and proceed likewise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked describes what happens when upgrading from free. Unused credit remains on the account. Resources stay running, now billable.

Thirty days is the free trial expiration grace period. (Which happens to be the same duration as the project deletion process). Storage is gone, but other objects may still exist. This is account cancellation, do not let it happen if you care about what you have built.

Ideally, any deleted resources were not the only copy. You wrote provisioning automation and took backups, and stored those outside of GCP.